# How to add Boost.Move library to CMakelists.txt?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Cannot compile C++ program, apparently because Boost.Move library is not added as dependency. Compilation errors related to unique_ptr. In the program I have several boost libraries as dependencies which I successfully added except boost.move. Went through a pile of examples and code, didn't file any specific examples on how to add it to CMakelists.txt.

Insets in my .cpp program (that's what it appears to be causing issues not having all dependencies):

```
#include <boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp>
...
boost::movelib::unique_ptr<plctag> _plctag;
...
```

My boost dependencies in CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS log thread)
```

Compilation errors, is it really what I'm thinking?:

```
path///.cpp:100:46: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  100 |             boost::movelib::unique_ptr<plctag> _plctag;
      |                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 path///.hpp:4,
                 path///.cpp:8:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:58:36: note: provided for ‘template<class T, class D> class boost::movelib::unique_ptr’
   58 | template< class T, class D > class unique_ptr;
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
path///.cpp:102:21: error: request for member ‘reset’ in ‘_tag’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  102 |             _tag.reset();
      |                     ^~~~~
path///.cpp:108:20: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
  108 |             _tag->write_tag_str();
      |                    ^~
path///.cpp:111:27: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
  111 |             string_vec = _tag->read_tag_str();
      |                           ^~
path///.cpp:125:20: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
  125 |             _tag->write_tag();
      |                    ^~
path///.cpp:128:27: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
  128 |             float_vec = _tag->read_tag();
```

Maybe I don't understand something. Pretty much a beginner at this point. Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i imagine the problem is in your code and is nothing to do with cmake

Comment: It looks like there's a forward declaration of the `boost::movelib::unique_ptr` that does not specify the default template parameter the way [the `boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp`  header](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/movelib/unique_ptr.html) does. Perhaps moving `#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>` so that it appears in `path.hpp` as the very first include could solve the issue...

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I would gladly do it but the whole program has so many dependencies, don't want to crowd the post. Just wanted to get opinions on my hypothesis, and a solution if it's right. I didn't add any dependency for boost move in cmake. Do you think it's not needed? Thanks a lot

Comment: @fabian: thank you for your comments. The code should be working. I pretty much copied it from proven github library. I must have built it wrongly. Do you think I don't need to add boost move dependency to compile it? I added just thread and log

Comment: The boost components *should* automatically add the necessary dependencies when linking the appropriate component using `target_link_libraries`. This should include adding any include dirs required to use headers used in the public headers of a lib, so `target_link_libraries(yourTarget PRIVATE Boost::thread)` should provide the necessary headers which should get you though the compilation and it does seem like the necessary headers are present (there's no error "include xy.hpp not found" or similar). My only guess right now is that there's something unexpected going on with the includes...

Comment: @fabian: thank you. I will look into it. What's the difference between adding boost libs with `find_package` and `target_link_libraries` like you mentioned? Thanks for help

Comment: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS a b c)` instructs cmake to search for an installed version of boost and instructs it to make certain data available for the boost specified components. In this case this includes making an imported cmake targets `Boost::<component name>` (like `Boost::thread`) available to you. Those imported libraries can contain info about additional requirements and possibly some other properties that are automatically applied on a target linking the imported boost target via `target_link_libraries`, so usually it's best to just do this to use the lib "as intended"...

Comment: Boost Move is header-only so nothing can be linked.